# Multi-threading: Unable to continue working in main thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I started learning python recently, and I am facing a situation that I do not even know if it is expected, or if something is wrong.

I am learning parallel threading to have two independent processes on the same program (UI control on one thread, image processing on another)

So, to test this I created this simple code:
(Camera is a custom class that connects to a usb webcam)

```
import thread
from vii.camera import Camera

class Process(object):

    def __init__(self, width=800, height=600):        
        self._cam = Camera(width, height)
        self._is_running = False
        self._current_image = None        

    def start(self):
        thread.start_new(self._run(), (self))

    def _run(self):
        self._cam.start()
        self._is_running = True

        while self._is_running:
            self._current_image = self._cam.update()
            self._current_image.show()

    def get_image(self):
        return self._current_image

    def stop(self):
        self._is_running = False        
        self._cam.close()
        thread.exit()


process = Process()
process.start() 

print("You will never see this output")

while (True):    
    key = raw_input()

    if key == 'q':        
        process.stop()
        break
```

The thread is created with success, and I am able to see the image. Now, I need to be able to affect it (stop it, get data from it) from the main thread. But the problem is that the code never enters in the while loop.

Is this behaviour expected? If it is, is there a way for me to achieve the functionality I need?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `thread` module, but this looks like the typical mistake everyone makes. Try changing `self._run()` to just `self._run`.

Comment: What @Rawing said, plus you should use `thread.start_new(self._run, (,))` since the method has no arguments other than `self`.

Comment: You guys are right, thanks.

Comment: Either way I am changing it to use the "threading" module, since some further research showed me that this is more widely used.